# How to sort a matrix in the descending order by the sum of its row in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix

My question is this: Given a matrix, sort it in the ascending order according to the sum of its rows. That is, if `A` is the following matrix:

```
A = [2, 5, 6, 1]
    [8, 2, 5, 3]
    [9, 7, 4, 6]
```

therefore, I would get:

```
B = [9, 7, 4, 6]
    [8, 2, 5, 3]
    [2, 5, 6, 1]
```

because the sum of the 1st row of `A` is `14`, the sum of the 2nd row of `A` is `18`, and the sum of the 3rd row of `A` is `26`. Hence, the 1st row of `B` will be the 3rd row of `A`, the 2nd row of `B` will be the 2nd row of `A`, and the 3rd row of `B` will be the 1st row of A.

I am looking for an algorithm, not for built-in function.

Comment: are you working with array or vector? "not for built-in function" means without standard library's algorithm?

Comment: `std::sort` accepts a custom sort function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easies way (but also the less efficient) is to use `selection sort`, so you take the smaller, you put it in first position, then you take the second smaller, and put it in the 2nd position and so on:

```
#include <iostream>

int sum(const int* array, int size){
    int tot = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++){
        tot+=array[i];
    }
    return tot;
}
void sort(int** matrix, int n_rows, int n_col){
    for(int i=0; i<n_rows-1; i++)
    {
        int min=i;
        for(int j=i+1; j<n_rows; j++)
            if (sum(matrix[j],n_col) > sum(matrix[min], n_col))
                min= j;
        auto temp=matrix[min];
        matrix[min]=matrix[i];
        matrix[i]=temp;
    }
}
// 2 5 6 1 8 2 5 3 9 7 4 6
int main(){
    int** array = new int*[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        int* tmp = new int[4];
        for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            std::cin >> tmp[j];
        }
        array[i] = tmp;
    }
    sort(array,3,4);
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        std::cout << '[';
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            std::cout << array[i][j];

        std::cout << ']' << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And if you need in the other verse, you just need to switch from:

```
if (sum(matrix[j],n_col) > sum(matrix[min], n_col))
```

to

```
if (sum(matrix[j],n_col) < sum(matrix[min], n_col))
```

and maybe change some variable name, like `min` should become `max`